# script preloading fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to preload my `js` files without executing them. My code is

```
for(var i=0; i<preload.length; i++){
        o = document.createElement('Object');
        o.data = preload[i];
        o.width  = 1;
        o.height = 1;
        o.style.visibility = "hidden";
        o.type = "text/cache";
        o.className = "hidden";
        console.log("Creating: ",o);

        o.onload = function(){
          console.info("Trying to load ",this.data," : ",i);
          itemloaded(this);
        }
        // all others require body
        document.body.appendChild(o);
      }
```

This works perfectly in firefox and IE but in chrome only the the log for `Creating` is triggered which shows `o` is an anonymous function, whereas FF and IE are reporting it as `Object`, and chrome never seems to trigger the `onload`

Comment: It might be a good idea to set up the "onload" handler *before* you set the URL (`data`).

Comment: @Pointy I also tried that but it made no difference

Answer (score -1):

why not use commonjs or amd?
or try this.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://path/to/your/script.js';
script.onload = function() {
// do something here
}

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: it's not a single script. I don't want to execute them till all of them has been loaded. Your method will execute the script automatically as soon as it is loaded